# Select with specified columns is not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in my PostgreSQL 10.1 database:

```
                                      Table "public.master_plan"
        Column        | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------------+------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
   start_time_utc     | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
   duration           | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
   date               | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
   team               | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
   spass_type         | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
   target             | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
   request_name       | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
   library_definition | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
   title              | text |           |          |         | extended |              | 
   description        | text |           |          |         | extended |              |
```

When I try the following sql query:

```
select title from master_plan;
```

it returns following error:

```
ERROR:  column "title" does not exist
LINE 1: select title from master_plan;
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "master_plan.  title".
```

What I'm doing wrong? This should work...

Comment: The column name `title` would appear to have spaces in it.  I believe I included this as an option in an answer on an earlier question.

Comment: I've tried with the spaces but the problem is the same...

Comment: In other database I write query like this: `select id from surveys;` and it works so why I need some spaces in column name...

Comment: What is your current default Schema? e.g. `SHOW_ search_path;`

Comment: search_path   
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)

Comment: Ok, that's good. Please run this too: `select column_name from information_schema.columns where
table_name='master_plan';`, unless you ran that to generate your example. If you haven't ran that, please include in the question body.

Comment: @JacobBarnes that didn't work also, the same error...

Comment: You have some odd Unicode things going on in your question's text, that `title` in `HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "master_plan.  title"` has, at least, some non-breaking space characters in it. Can you double check that the column name really is the five characters `t`, `i`, `t`, `l`, `e`?

Comment: What @muistooshort is very likely. I was hoping that would be made clear by the results of the first query I commented with.

Comment: Here is how I create table:

create table master_plan(
  start_time_utc text,
  duration text,
  date text,
  team text,
  spass_type text,
  target text,
  request_name text,
  library_definition text,
  title text,
  description text
);

Comment: Have a look at that `create table` in a hex editor, it is loaded with \u202f characters (AKA "narrow no-break space"). Perhaps you have an encoding problem somewhere that is making a mess of things.

Comment: I'm typing this create table statement directly inside sql console so I think that this is not the problem. I'm using Mac OSX High Sierra if that matters.

Comment: You may have right, I've found that when I copy text from my sublime text it not works. But when I type it directly into psql column it works. What can be wrong in my editor?

Comment: I've not used Sublime text, but Notepad++ is able to show all hidden characters. Sublime must have a similar feature or it wouldn't be a staple tool. In Notepad++ it is View -> Show Symbols -> Show all Characters

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces in the name. Try this:

```
alter table master_plan rename column "  title" to title;
select title from master_plan;
```

or

```
alter table master_plan rename column "master_plan.  title" to title;
select title from master_plan;
```

You can see a running example at: http://rextester.com/LCXW46910